# Max y min en una sola consulta

Tags: sql, postgresql

Pregunta de mi bendito examen el día de hoy:

Queremos ver qué empleado ha vendido más con el total de sus pedidos y qué
ha vendido menos -Cantidad de dinero siempre, no de comandes-. Por eso queremos una consulta con 4 columnas:

- código del empleado como code,
- nombre del empleado como name,
- ciudad de la oficina del empleado como city,
- total del importe de las ventas que ha hecho como sum.

Ordenar desde el que ha comprado más al que ha comprado menos.

En caso de que hubiera un empate tanto en primera como en última posición sería necesario que se mostraran TODOS los vendedores que están empatados ordenados por código.

```
 code |    name     |    city     |   sum    
------+-------------+-------------+----------
--More--
```

¿Alguna solución?

Solo llegue a este punto ... y no se como coger solo la primera línea (max gastado) y la ultima(min gastado).

```
select num_empl,nombre, (select ciudad from oficinas where oficina_rep=oficina), (select sum(importe) from pedidos where rep=num_empl group by rep) from repventas group by num_empl
order by 4 DESC
OFFSET 1;    #el offset es para quitar un campo vacio
```

```
 num_empl |    nombre     |   ciudad    |   sum    
----------+---------------+-------------+----------

      108 | Larry Fitch   | Los Angeles | 58633.00
      105 | Bill Adams    | Atlanta     | 39327.00
      107 | Nancy Angelli | Denver      | 34432.00
      106 | Sam Clark     | New York    | 32958.00
      101 | Dan Roberts   | Chicago     | 26628.00
      110 | Tom Snyder    |             | 23132.00
      102 | Sue Smith     | Los Angeles | 22776.00
      109 | Mary Jones    | New York    |  7105.00
      103 | Paul Cruz     | Chicago     |  2700.00
```

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para darle un mejor formato, sugiero que le des clic en [edit] y observes como se hace para hacerlo tu mismo. También te invito a que cuides tu ortografía, es básica para poder darse a entender. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas para obtener el resultado que quieres. Sería bueno de todas formas que pusieras en tu pregunta la estructura de tus tablas, así como también algunos datos de ejemplo.

Una alternativa es la siguiente:

```
WITH Ventas AS
(
    SELECT 
        rv.num_empl AS code,
        rv.nombre AS "name",
        o.ciudad AS city,
        SUM(p.importe) AS "sum"
    FROM repventas rv
    INNER JOIN oficinas o
        ON o.oficina = rv.oficina_rep
    INNER JOIN pedidos p
        ON p.rep = rv.num_empl
    GROUP BY 
        rv.num_empl,
        rv.nombre,
        o.ciudad
)
SELECT *
FROM Ventas v
WHERE "sum" = (SELECT MAX("sum") FROM Ventas)
OR "sum" = (SELECT MIN("sum") FROM Ventas)
;
```